# Copying from asset to sdcard open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, sd-card, assets

I am try to copy from asset to sdcard
Here is part of my code

```
private void CopyAssets(String folder) {

        File folders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/beatscache/"+folder);
        folders.mkdirs();
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
                try {
            files = assetManager.list(folder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        for(String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
              in = assetManager.open(folder+"/"+filename);   // if files resides inside the "Files" directory itself
              out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+"beatscache"+"/"+folder +"/" + filename);
              copyFile(in, out);
              in.close();
              in = null;
              out.flush();
              out.close();
              out = null;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
          out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

And

```
CopyAssets("bin");
```

Log shows

> E/tag(3801): /mnt/sdcard/beatscache/bin/alsa_ctl: open failed: ENOENT
>   (No such file or directory)

I have given READ and WRITE permissions in AndroidManifest.xml
and checked Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) returns true.

And folder is not getting created.

Can you tell where I am doing wrong.?

Answer (score 2):

Check if file is exists or not first then move your content there

```
final File dir = new File(cEnvironment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/beatscache/"+folder +"/");
if(dir.exists()==false)
{
dir.mkdirs(); //create folders where write files
final File file = new File(dir, filename);
}
```

Comment: How can checking will solve the open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)?

Comment: if the directory/file is not existed then this type of errors occur. so first of check whether they existed. if not then create them.will solve the problem'

Comment: if you see my code,in second line itself it should create /sdcard/beatscache/bin/ folder but during runtime it is not creating any folder.

Comment: is that folder created in your sdcard?

Comment: try to check once again with this code `File folders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/beatscache/"+folder);`